# CS50542 and CS0103 adter converting a vb project containing a wpf control to c# using code converter

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have a vb project that contains a wpf control
I am using [Code Converter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.CodeConverter) to do the conversion
After running the converter and building I get the following buid errors

```
Error   CS0542  'SpellControl': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
```

and

```
Error   CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
```

The xaml is

```
<UserControl x:Class="SpellControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textSpell" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-AU" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Loaded="textSpell_Loaded">
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the UserControl code to add the namespace

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProjectNamespace.SpellControl"
```

Where MyProjectNamespace is the Default Namespace in the project application tab.

This resolved the CS0103 error

To resolve the CS50542 error I just had to remove the generated control initializer

```
public partial class SpellControl
{
    public SpellControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //public void SpellControl()
    //{
    //}
```

Comment: Yes, VB and C# handle "project namespaces" differently